# Table row click listener stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding rows to a table dynamically using the following function. Upon a row click the table disappears and another div is generated and populated dynamically. It was all working perfectly till 2 hours ago, when suddenly without me changing any code it stopped. I am not sure if the following code is sufficient enough for someone to give me an answer but does anyone see any particular reason this will stop working all of the sudden ?

```
var setupProjectListTable = function (ipProject, table, tableContainer) {
    $('#' + table + ' tr').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    var title             = ipProject.getTitle();
    var desc              = ipProject.getDesc();
    var applicableDegrees = ipProject.getApplicableDegreeList();
    var keywordList       = ipProject.getKeywordList();
    $('#' + table + ' tbody').append(
        '<tr id = "' + title             + '">'    +
        '<td>'       + title             + '</td>' +
        '<td>'       + desc              + '</td>' +
        '<td>'       + applicableDegrees + '</td>' +
        '<td>'       + keywordList       + '</td></tr>'
    );
    $("#" + title).click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + tableContainer).hide();
        generateProjectDetails(ipProject);
    });
};
```

Comment: jsfiddle please. Are you getting any javascript errors? what happens now?

Comment: No errors what so ever, I tried console logging the click listener but it seems it's not even recording a click. Also my code is separated into a lot of classes it will be really hard for me to upload everything there and I need to get this up and going asap, I was hoping that some1 might see a common mistake in it or something :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. `click()` Only affects existing elements but not added elements.

so use `on()`:

```
$("tbody").on('click', '#' + title, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#' + tableContainer).hide();
    generateProjectDetails(ipProject);
});
```

Comment: If the node that has the id '#' + title was dynamically generated, and may soon be dereferenced (and eventually gc'd), I guess this delegated handler will get left dangling / still hang around? I suppose it probably doesn't really matter, since the whole page will probably be gc'd before the number of those becomes significant. Still, it bugs me a little; but I haven't come up with a better way that doesn't involve adding a bunch of code.